# Style of the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

In my document I only use \part and \chapter. That makes my table of contents look like strange. Is there a way to display my parts as chapers and my chapters as sections please?
I tried whith the package [tocstyle](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{FAVIER David}
\rfoot{\thepage\ sur \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
    %\vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
    %\vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}
\section{Section}
\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why din't you use `\chapter` and `\section`s from the start?

Comment: Actually I'm using sections and subsections in the document but without being numbering : \section*{}.. I would like to change the table of contents

Comment: `\makeatletter
  \let\l@part\l@chapter
  \let\l@chapter\l@section\makeatother`

Comment: Use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to have unnumbered sections by default.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please post that in the answer section so I mark my question as answered.

Comment: I bet this question has been asked before. Let me check and we can close as duplicate. Other users find solutions faster that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```
\makeatletter
\let\l@part\l@chapter 
\let\l@chapter\l@section
\makeatother
```